# Angular ui-select with or conditioned filter

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I am trying to use or condition filter in ui select and I am not sure how to process that. I have a similar question answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103867/angular-ui-select-filtering-only-one-field). But that is asked for using AND condition which works for me too. Here is my code

**HTML**

```
<ui-select ng-model="citySelected">
    <ui-select-match>
        {{$select.selected.name + ', ' + $select.selected.country}}
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="city in List | filter: {name: $select.search} | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
        <span ng-bind-html="city.name + ', ' + city.country| highlight: $select.search"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using a properties filter to search through any of the parameters that I have specified.

```
    app.filter('propsFilter', function() {
       return function(items, props) {
           var out = [];

           if (angular.isArray(items)) {
               items.forEach(function(item) {
               var itemMatches = false;

               var keys = Object.keys(props);
               for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                   var prop = keys[i];
                   var text = props[prop].toLowerCase();
                   if (item[prop].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1){
                       itemMatches = true;
                       break;
                   }
                }

                if (itemMatches) {
                  out.push(item);
                }
             });
           } else {
           // Let the output be the input untouched
               out = items;
           }

           return out;
         }
    });

 //To use add this to UI-Selet Where you are using filter
 <ui-select-choices repeat="city in List | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, secondFilter: $select.search, third: $select.search} | orderBy:'sortOrder'">
```

Comment: I have a similar custom filter written. But all of a sudden it has stopped working. The filter doesn't even get called.. The only thing I changed was that I deployed it onto a different server. Did you face such issue?