# ui-select search on specific object properties

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, ui-select

Can I filter my search in `ui-select` on specific fields of my object? Or should I create a custom filter? I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103867/angular-ui-select-filtering-only-one-field) and it says it works, but my following code is not working:

```
<ui-select ng-model="model.selected">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span class="ng-cloak">{{$select.selected.id ? $select.selected.id+ ' (' + $select.selected.sn + ') ' : "Select One" }}</span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | filter: {id: $select.search.id, sn: $select.search.sn}">
        <span ng-bind="(item.id) + ' (' + (item.sn)  + ') ' "></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the each `item` in `items` has the following attributes:

- id
- sn
- fn

Given the following dataset:

```
[ 
    {"id":"Ja111", "sn":"Jacobs","fn":"Jim"},
    {"id":"Ja222", "sn":"Jagger","fn":"Robert"},
    {"id":"Jo111", "sn":"Jones","fn":"Stan"},
    {"id":"J111", "sn":"Johnson","fn":"Alfred"},
    {"id":"Sm111", "sn":"Smith","fn":"Joe"}
]
```

using:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | filter: {id: $select.search, sn: $select.search}">
```

will perform an "and" operation on the specified fields (in this case `id` and `sn`) (e.g. the search criteria "Jo" will find only "Stan Jones")

using:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | filter: $select.search">
```

will perform an "or" operation across all fields (e.g. the search criteria "Jo" will find "Stan Jones", "Alfred Johnson" and "Joe Smith")

using:

```
<ui-select-choices repeat="item in items | propsFilter: {id: $select.search, sn: $select.search}">
```

will perform an "or" operation on the specified fields (in this case `id` and `sn`) (e.g. the search criteria "Jo" will find "Stan Jones" and "Alfred Johnson" - note it won't find "Joe Smith" as the filter is not looking at the `fn` field)

The following [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zGq7f05PynrXaKmGupu6?p=preview) shows the above examples in action.

For your requirements (I assume you want an "or" filter but only on specific fields) I'd go down the `propsFilter` route. This seems to be what the [ui-select Basic Demo](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-select/#examples) uses too.